# Application for manage and sync PDF collection

Tags: pdf, books, icloud

Unfortunately is not possible synch the PDFs files  using iBook, so i'm looking for an alternative.
I have a huge collection of PDF file and i work with different computers.

I'm looking for an application that can takes care of all my PDFs and generate an archive that can be put on Dropbox / iCloud Drive.

Sometink like [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) but possibly with a better UX. It shouldn't be necessarely free.

Thanks.

Comment: See: BibDesk, Papers, or Mendeley.

Comment: I have no problems syncing PDF files in iBooks via iTunes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of these for PDF management:

http://reinventedsoftware.com/together/
This works with iCloud to access your library on multiple devices

http://www.ironicsoftware.com/yep/

You can also attach PDF's to notes in evernote.com

Comment: together seems to be a nice app, i will try for a couple of week. thanks.